# Android: Create custom TextView carded

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to learn custom view. in order to i've created a class called EditTextCarded that extended CardView.
In `init` method i have initialized a EditText and assigned layout params to it.
After overriding **onMeasure** method and declare view size,
and after that by running my customView, just card view is appeared on the screen and EditText does not exist into CardView or is invisible.What's happend and where is my textView?

```
class EditTextCarded @JvmOverloads
constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int = 0) : CardView(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {


    init {
        var editText = EditText(context)
        editText.layoutParams = LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT))
        editText.hint = "Test"
        addView(editText)
    }

    override fun onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec: Int, heightMeasureSpec: Int) {
        ....
    }
}
```

my XML layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="#eee"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.groot.edittext_carded.MainActivity">

    <com.example.groot.edittext_carded.EditTextCarded
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CardView.LayoutParams for adding childviews in into CardView

```
public class EditTextCarded extends CardView {

private EditText editText;

public EditTextCarded(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(context);
}

public EditTextCarded(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context);
}

public EditTextCarded(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int 
defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init(context);
}

private void init(Context context) {
    editText = new EditText(context);
    editText.setHint("EditText");
    CardView.LayoutParams clp = new 
CardView.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    addView(editText,clp);
}
}
```

Xml

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<com.example.groot.edittext_carded.EditTextCarded
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: CardView does not have any LayoutParams!!! maybe i have to use `FrameLayout.LayoutParams` instead of CardView.LayoutParams!

Comment: use code in answer. CardView child class of FrameLayout. CardView uses FrameLayout.LayoutParams

Comment: dude when i use CardView.LayoutParams i got this error : `unresolve reference LayoutParams`

Comment: when i have overriden `onMeasure` method , textview is gone!! should i have to override `onMeasure` method? or `onMeasure` method just use for view

Comment: why should you onMeasure. What do you want to do in onMeasure? check this links https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onMeasure(int, int)

Comment: I don't want to anything. I am just practicing.I saw people use onMeasure method for getting `width` and `height` from xml layout

Comment: check this links https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onMeasure(int, int)  and https://medium.com/@quiro91/custom-view-mastering-onmeasure-a0a0bb11784d